# How can I force SQL Azure to accept DMY in query string?

Tags: asp-classic, azure, azure-sql-database

We have a range of legacy applications that we are trying to migrate to SQL Azure. The applications are written in Classic ASP with lots of string based queries. There are to many to rewrite to make it worth migrating.

Any queries with dates are failing as the SQL string queries use UK DMY format. SQL Azure user and DB seem hard set to use use US English format.

If I add SET DATEFORMAT dmy; before a query string the query then works. However this requires change thousands of queries. Is there anyway to force SQL Azure to use DMY format as part of the connection string? That or or some other solution that saves us re-writing thousands of queries? Any way to set a login to always use DMY format or to have the whole DB use DMY etc?

Thanks

Graeme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what Richard was suggesting is something like this:

Original code:

```
Dim rs
Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADO.Recordset")
... recordset shiznit ...
Set rs = nothing
```

New code:

```
Dim rs
Set rs = New cHomegrownAdoRecordsetWrapper
... same unchanged recordset shiznit ...
Set rs = nothing
```

If the code is in VBScript, though, you would have a hard time implementing this.

The first problem you'd run in to [if you tried doing it natively in VBScript] is that ADO Recordset object makes heavy use of optional arguments in its methods, and you simply can't create a function (or class method) in VBScript that has optional arguments. Therefore you wouldn't be able to subclass anything useful.

You could possibly subclass the ADo recordset object in JScript though - it is possible to mix and match both languages in the same script using  in the same page; just realize anything that is JScript will get executed first, no matter where it is in the page. ASP runs the JScript interpreter first, and then the VBScript interpreter second.

You might also be able to create your own Com-based DLL that wrapped the ADO object... but you'd have to investigate that yourself.

Now.

If it were me, I'd take a serious look at search & replace, depending on how consistent the code is.

If you can get the code to the point where the inline queries are using "dd FullMonthName YYYY", i.e. an unambiguous date format, you won't need to worry about the DMY issue with the database, and the code will survive on whatever version of SQL it's running against.

As long as dates have a text-based month name, and a full year, SQL it doesn't care what order they're in.

I suspect you might even be able to take Richard's idea on a smaller scale, and put a wrapper function wherever there is an inline date, do a bit of runtime sniffing, and get everything working again.

Comment: Like the idea of custom ADO DLL - sounds sensible but I doubt I am going to get time to do it. Given that its all in VBScript I think it is find and replace. I guess all SQL will start with a Select, Insert,Update or Delete or a call to a stored proc. Just add the set dateformat DMY part at the beginning of every SQL string and it should be good. I prefer the idea of changing all of the dates to use "dd FullMonthName YYYY" format but that would be more time consuming. I wish I could just force SQL Azure to use British Date format for one login etc. or set it in the connection string.

Answer (score 1):

You could subclass the connection itself so that whenever a command was sent it was preceded by the SET DATEFORMAT command. This would entail a refactoring of your engine but that could be achieved by a search-replace.

Comment: What would that look like in Classic ASP? I didn't think it supported most OO stuff. All our connections are based on ADODB.Recordset